# How can I move this file away?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have identified the file that prevent me from further shrinking C: partition for Windows 7 OS.

By query shrinking and then checking Event Viewer, this is the file:

> The last unmovable file appears to be:
>   \ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Wi
>   ndows\Projects\SystemIndex\Indexer\CiFiles\0001001
>   5.wid::$DATA

I was wondering how to move this file away? I guess I have to move the whole \ProgramData away, not just that file?

Comment: can you copy the file, then delete the original?

Comment: 3rd party partition software will be more intelligent than Windows shrink, it will move the necessary files....http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by “move away”? Delete or move to another drive?

If you delete the file, then file-searching performance will be reduced until the Indexer can rebuild the database by scanning all of your files again (though you could also just move the file to another disk for a while then move it back).

1. Open an elevated command prompt: `Start->cmd.exe->Shift+Enter`
2. Now stop the Search Indexer: `net stop WSearch`
3. The file should be unlocked and movable/deletable

Once you’ve shrunk the partition, reboot to restart the Indexer (or start it manually) to have it rebuild the database.

Comment: the 'net stop' command didn't work for me (permissions error), but using the services snap-in to stop the service did, and this helped unlock the file.

Comment: You have to run it from an administrator command-prompt.